# Certification date vs certificate date

Tags: word-choice

In company XYZ people can get a certificate called 'XYZ certified professional'. This certificate has a date and the certificate is valid for a number of years from that date onwards.

Which is the best description for this date?

> 1. Certification date
> 2. Certificate date

I would intuitively choose 1, but 2 has the advantage of being shorter.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Certification date is when the person obtained the certification, Certificate date is the date on the certificate - e.g. when it was created

Comment: Either sound acceptable but do they mean exactly the same thing? *Certificate date* sounds like the date the certificate was written - which could be the same as *certification date*. But if there is a procedure whereby certificates are renewed (say annually) then will the date on any certificate necessarily be the same as that of original *certification*?

Comment: @WS2 and mplungjan you raise a good point, so I guess 1 is better because it removes a potential ambiguity. If you want to write this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either sound acceptable but do they mean exactly the same thing? Certificate date sounds like the date the certificate was written - which could be the same as certification date. But if there is a procedure whereby certificates are renewed (say annually) then will the date on any certificate necessarily be the same as that of original certification? –

Answer (score 4):

Generally, though, you can use whatever terminology you like so long as you are consistent. The following might be an example.

- The *certificate date* is whatever date is printed on the certificate, whether it is the first time that certificate was awarded to a specific professional or not.
- The *certification date* is the date when the professional first completed certification.
- The *recertification date* is the date when that professional completed recertification.